# Why Node.js can not import module? Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]

Tags: node.js

I run

```
node --experimental-modules simpledemo.mjs
```

Simple2.mjs(book Node.js Complete Reference Guide)

```
var count = 0;
export function next() { return ++count; }
function squared() { return Math.pow(count, 2); }
export function hello() {
  return "Hello, world!";
}

export default function() { return count; }

export const meaning = 42;
export let nocount = -1;
export { squared };
```

Got an error

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^


  Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/mi/pract/simple2.mjs' imported from /home/mi/pract/simpledemo.mjs
```

Tree

```
tree .
.
├── simple2.msj
├── simpledemo.mjs
└── simple.js

0 directories, 3 files
```

Import line(edited by looking previous SO posts)

```
import * as simple2 from '/home/mi/pract/simple2.mjs';
```

Node version

```
v14.8.0
```

How to resolve import?

Comment: have you tried to import is relatively, e.g. `... from './simple2.mjs'`?

Comment: @Sgnl Got the same error.

Comment: what are the contents of `simple2.mjs`? is it exporting a module properly?